# Setting child list value from grand parent class

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

Parent Component having a child AddHospitalComponent.
AddHospitalComponent again have  a child  AddDepartmentComponent.

AddDepartmentComponent having a list departmentList;

Want to set this departmentList value from the HospitalsComponent, but it returns error . "Cannot set property 'departmentList' of undefined".

How can I set the  AddHospitalComponent component before setting departmentList, I dont have anything to set for AddHospitalComponent.

This is the grand parent class.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-hospitals',
  templateUrl: './add-hospitals.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./add-hospitals.component.scss']
})
export class HospitalsComponent implements OnInit {

  @ViewChild(AddHospitalComponent, { static: true }) newHospital: AddHospitalComponent;
  constructor(public router: Router) { 

  }


  loadById(event: any) {
    this.hospitalService.getHospitalsById(event).subscribe(response => { //server call

      this.newHospital.hospDepartment.departmentList = []; // line 6
        if (response) {
        this.newHospital.hosp = new HospitalModel();
        this.newHospital.hosp = response['result'];
        this.newHospital.hospDepartment.departmentList = this.newHospital.hospital.hospDepartmentList;

      }

    })
}
```

on line 6 I am getting error "Cannot set property 'departmentList' of undefined".

corresponding html for grand parent

### add-hospitals.component.html

```
<div class="pl-2">
           <button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" (click)="loadById(val)">Save</button>
          <app-add-hospital  #newHospital></app-add-hospital>
      </div>
```

This is the parent class.

```
 export class AddHospitalComponent implements OnInit {

      constructor(private masterService:MasterService) { }

      @ViewChild(AddDepartmentComponent, { static: true }) hospDepartment: AddDepartmentComponent;

      }
```

This is the child class, need to se this departmentList in child class from grand parent.

```
export class AddDepartmentComponent implements OnInit {

  departmentList: DepartmentModel[] = [];
  }
```

Comment: Is you `newHospital` parent component has `*ngIf` on it's tag or one of it's parent tags? In other words, can you upload your grand parent html?

Comment: @benshabatnoam question updated.

Comment: yes I do have an *ngIf and that is the reason for this issue.

Answer (score 0):

In that case you need to be sure that your child and grand child component's view are instanciated before you assign to the grand child component properties.

A simple solution would be set a timer in a ngAfterViewInit hook to be sure child views are instanciated.

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    timer(250).subscribe(() => {
         // assign grand child variables
    });
}
```

While this should be enough for it to work, it's super optimized. Another idea could be to have outputs on your grand child and child components, and trigger an event on ngAfterViewInit of the child component to nofity its view is ready, and that the grand child component properties are accessible using ViewChild.
Listen to this output in the main component and assign variables when it is fired.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever a `@ViewChild` component is wrapped a round with an `*ngIf` directive you should define your `@ViewChild` variable in the next way:

```
newHospital: AddHospitalComponent;
@ViewChild(AddHospitalComponent, { static: true }) set Content(newHospitalRef) {
  this.newHospital = newHospitalRef;
}
```

This syntax will execute `set Content` function each time your component gets created/destroyed. This way you can save the component's reference once it's gets created and be sure that it's not `undefined`.

Comment: Cannot set property 'departmentList' of undefined .. same error

Comment: @user630209 That's wired. Can you debug if the function gets executed? if not debug then add 'console.log' to it... Anyway in this stage it will be best that you'll make some kind of a simple demo project (in StackBlitz or others) reproducing this, so we could help further...